# Network Printing in Fedora

Tags: networking, firewall, printing

I´m having problems setting up network printing in Fedora 16. In the printer setup box it says FirewallD is not running and gives a list of protocols that need to be enabled. I cannot find a FirewallD but have gone into Firewall and enabled the protocols. There is obviously something I´m missing.

The printer is a Canon MP970 and is connected to a Windows machine.

**Update: 4Nov12**

Bought a new printer - same problem. This time I set it up properly as a network printer. Windows 7 and Ubuntu both find the printer and print fine. Fedora still complains FirewallD is not running.

The new printer is a Canon MG6250. I have installed the drivers from RPM packages.

Comment: Is the printer itself on the network. Can you ping it from Fedora?

Comment: No. It is connected via USB.

Comment: Printer has a network jack in it, so have plugged it in. Now what? It´s IP is 10.0.0.111

Comment: See if you can ping it. Also try telnetting to it. Then you need to figure out if you can get a driver for it. From a quick Google, it looks like the support is dodgy.

Comment: You might find this helpful - http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Canon/Canon-MULTIPASS-MP970 There is a lot of other random stuff scattered across the web of course, but I can't test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the [answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/639/setup-network-samba-printer) in the [Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/questions/) forums. Someone there had the same problem and one of the responces said to enter `system-config-printer` into Terminal and configure the printer that way. I can now print!

Comment: Both links end up at "Page Not Found".